# How to read the content of service bus messages only for monitoring

Tags: .net, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Is there a way to read messages in Queue or Topics without pulling it or changing any behavior (just for monitoring)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Service Bus allows to peek messages.

For example, you can use a [`QueueClient.PeekAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.queueclient.peekasync.aspx) to to peek messages from a queue. There's an equivalent for [topics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt621607.aspx) and [subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj908822.aspx) as well.

In case you don't need to differentiate between messages from queues and subscriptions, there's a [`MessageReceiver.PeekAsync()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn130294.aspx) option.

Comment: thanks for answering. Is there anyway to let the sender knows that the message has been read ?

Comment: Peeking messages doesn't modify the message. If you refer that the message was consumed (as in read), that would be beyond broker's responsibility. In that case, I would say your consumer has to reply to the producer or somehow indicate that the message is processed. Have a look at NServiceBus or MassTransit that can help you with these kind of scenarios.

Comment: Thanks!
My case with ServiceBus topic is that I have many subscriptions (not known how many) and all of them should receive the message. I need a way in the sender to indicate the message has been consumed by all of them.

I know that the message won't be active anymore once it is consumed from all clients, but how to know this in the sender side? keep trying to fetch it every few seconds and once it is gone it is been consumed? is this the only way?

Comment: I think the problem is with the approach.Subscriptions are for events. Events are notifications about something that took place and at it's core it suppose to decouple between publishers and subscribers. If your sender knows how many event consumers are out there, the design doesn't sound right.